# How to get different clazz/flags for roundabout?

Tags: osm2po

I'm using osm2po to import Open Street Map data. I want to get information about roundabouts. In the final SQL file I need to know if a road is part of a roundabout or not.

The only way to get this information in the SQL file is to change the clazz or flag value.

How can I get a different clazz value for roundabouts?

I have tried to change the configuration file but without any effect :

```
wtr.tag.junction.roundabout =    1, 77, 35
```

I never get 77 value in clazz column.

Answer (score 2):

`junction=roundabout` needs some (hard coded) extra handling with reference to the oneways. Because of this fact, I've mistakenly isolated it in an else-block where the configuration could not override it. This will be fixed in the next version.

Nevertheless, `junction=roundabout` is not a main-tag. It's an additional tag to e.g. `highway=xxx`. But if you need it as a road-clazz, you can declare it the way above. In this case you'll have to take the concurrent order into account. Meaning, you should give it precedence over highway-tags (see first parameter '1').
If you only need the information "this is a roundabout", use the wtr.allow...-tag instead.